# give function to rendered attribute

Tags: apex, visualforce, map, rendered

I have a visualforce page that uses various components to try to print data from a list of custom objects. The idea is that it will display a list of types of relationships and then if clicked it will display the names of people who have that type of relationship.

In my controller I have a:

`Map<String, List<Relationship_Detail__c>> typeToRelationships`

where it takes the relationship type as the key and gives back all of the custom objects with that type.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!typeToRelationships}" var="relationshipType" rendered="{!IF(sortedByType==true, true, false)}">
    <apex:commandLink action="{!relationshipTypeClicked}" rerender="relationsWithType">
        <apex:outputText value="{!relationshipType} ({!typeToNumberOfRelationships[relationshipType]})"/>
        <apex:param name="relationType" value="{!relationshipType}" assignTo="{!selectedType}"/>
        <apex:param name="idOfViewer" value="{!contact.Id}" assignTo="{!selectedIDForType}"/>
    </apex:commandLink>
    <apex:outputPanel id="relationsWithType" >
        <apex:dataList value="{!typeToRelationships[relationshipType]}" var="relation" rendered="{!IF(rendered[relationshipType]==true, true, false)}">
            <apex:commandLink action="{!relationDetailClicked}">
                various outputTexts
            </apex:commandLink>
        </apex:dataList>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:repeat>
```

I want to modify it so that the string is the `relationship type + the id of the contact page` I am currently on.

The issue in doing that is with the dataList in the middle of the given code which renders based on a `Map<String, Boolean>` called `rendered`, which takes the same key and spits out true or false.

The code used `rendered={!IF(rendered[relationshipType]`... for the dataList but now I want to do something like this:

`rendered={!IF(rendered[relationshipType+contact.id]`.

Is this possible? Or is there a way to have the rendered attribute call a function with those parameters which would return true or false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to pass parameters to a controller method binding in a Visualforce page. From [Controller Methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_methods.htm):

> Visualforce markup can use the following types of controller extension and custom controller methods:
>
> - Action
> - Getter
> - Setter

You could rework `typeToRelationships` so that the keys already contain concatenated relationshipType and contact.Id.

Alternatively, you could put the apex:dataList into an apex:component. The component can have multiple apex:attributes defined. This will allow you to pass multiple parameters in.

---

One small personal crusade. The following is perfectly valid. However, it does contain a large amount of redundancy.

```
rendered="{!IF(sortedByType==true, true, false)}"
```

Instead, consider:

```
rendered="{!sortedByType}"
```

There is no need to compare a boolean to another boolean or wrap it in an IF statement.

Comment: Thank you very much and thank you for catching that redundancy. I will certainly look into the apex:component